# Can Javascript read data from external files or store data in temporary files for later usage?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to extract location names from search results of search engine and translate them into codinates which can be taken as input for Google maps API.

I have seen examples calling Google maps API in javascript so I am asking can js read external files (which contains codinates for Google maps API) then show the map along the search results.

Another idea is that if js can directly extract location names and store them somewhere, if possible, and then call Web services to translate location names to codinates and store them somewhere. Finally js call Google maps API and display the map along the search results.

This is my rough idea and please feel free to give other suggestions to achieve this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To access from or to write to file, you can make use jQuery library.

To know about accessing from a file, go through this link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

In order to write to a file, I have a sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function WriteToFile()
{
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var s = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\Test.txt", true);
    s.WriteLine('Hello');
    s.Close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="WriteToFile()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data locally in the local browser for future use, then you would use either cookies (all browsers) or for more data, you could use HTML5 local storage (modern browsers only).

Javascript from a browser, by itself, cannot access local files on the local hard disk (for security reasons).

Javascript can read files on a remote server as long as those files are accessible via the public internet.  There are any number of ways to retrieve those external files.  You can use an ajax GET to read them and many libraries (like jQuery or YUI) have library support for retrieving external files and parsing the data (JSON, XML, etc...).

If you want to store data on a server, you can use either a form POST or ajax calls to send the data to your server where the server can then store it for later retrieval.